# Swapping Keys and Values in a Dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, swap

I'm trying to swap the keys and values of my dict, and although I've searched online and found ways of doing it, I keep getting an error.

```
def dict_reverser(dict1, dict2):
    for k, v in dict2.items():
        if v in dict1:
            dict1[v].append(k)
        else:
            dict1[v] = k

    print(dict1)

exampleDict = {"Ice": "Cream", "Age": "21", "Light": "Cream", "Double": "Cream"}
myDict = {}

dict_reverser(myDict, exampleDict)
```

The error I get is:

```
dict1\[v\].append(k)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I've tried dict[v] += k but that just concatinates everything, as to be expected.

Edit: Desired output:
{'Cream': ['Ice', 'Light', 'Double'] '21': 'Age'}

Comment: `dict1[v]` returns the value for key `v` which is a str, not a list hence the error. If you want to append values `dict1[v] += k`

Comment: What is your desired output? i.e. what `myDict` should look like after the reverse?

Comment: I think you need to replace `dict1[v] = k` with `dict1[v] = [k]`

Comment: `.append()` is a list method, but none of the keys or values in `dict2` are lists.  How did you expect to get a list?

Comment: @LMC dict1[v] += k concatenates the values, giving  'Cream': 'IceLightDouble'

Comment: Your desired output doesn't make sense. Is it a list? Is it a string? Who knows!

Comment: `dict1.setdefault(v, []).append(k)` can replace the entire `if` statement (though the answer demonstrating the use of `collections.defaultdict` is probably preferable).

Answer (score 2):

Use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to create your list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

example_dict = {"Ice": "Cream", "Age": "21", "Light": "Cream", "Double": "Cream"}
my_dict = defaultdict(list)


def dict_reverser(my_dict, example_dict):
    for key, value in example_dict.items():
        my_dict[value].append(key)
    return dict(my_dict)
        
        
test = dict_reverser(my_dict, example_dict)
print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sudden_appearance for the answer I was looking for. I think roganjosh may have also given a solution but I'm too much of a noobie to know understand -
Answer:
change dict1[v].append(k) to dict1[v] += [k]
and dict1[v] = k to dict1[v] = [k]
Fully:

```py
def dict_reverser(dict1, dict2):
    for k, v in dict2.items():
        if v in dict1:
            dict1[v] += [k]
        else:
            dict1[v] = [k]

    print(dict1)

exampleDict = {"Ice": "Cream", "Age": "21", "Light": "Cream", "Double": "Cream"}
myDict = {}

dict_reverser(myDict, exampleDict)
```